# Getting Connection Timeout when trying to send HTTPS Get request

Tags: java, ssl, https, proxy, get

I have tried sending an HTTPS Get request to https://google.com by using native Java classes, Apache HttpClient, and Spring's restTemplate but all three have ended with the same issue: Connection Exception: connect timeout error.

Calls to http://www.google.com work just fine, its only when I use https that the timeout happens

I am behind a corporate firewall so I did some reading up on allowing requests to use a proxy. I have set the -Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort environment variables, as well as -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore environment variable. I made sure that Googles Root SSL Cert is in the trustStore's list of qualified certs.

Ideally I will be using spring's rest template so I have the following code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://www.google.com";
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

After running with debugger I see that it gets stuck at line 2, when it is supposed to be making the request. When I viewed the network traffic using Fiddler I saw that an http call is made to localhost, and that is the call that times out. I never saw an HTTPS call made to https://www.google.com. This is very hard for me to fix because I cant tell if it is a proxy issue or some environment set up issue.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your code works here, I get response html

Comment: So if it works for you and not me, it must be something to do with my proxy correct?

Comment: probably yes, try to set your proxy like this      System.setProperty("https.proxyHost",ip);
     System.setProperty("https.proxyPort",port);

Comment: I forgot to mention that a call to "http://www.google.com" works just fine. its only when I use https that all calls get a timeout. So it seems to me that it is not a proxy issue because I am able to get external http calls successfully